# How to manipulate elements in a network table?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to learn about manipulating Netlogo tables. Given the following:

```
extensions [table]
globals [t]

to test
  set t table:make
  table:put t 1 [[50 1] [55 2]]
  table:put t 2 [[20 3] [15 4]]
  table:put t 3 [[35 4] [45 5] [50 6]]
end
```

which produces the following table:

```
1, 50, 1
1, 55, 2
2, 20, 3
2, 15, 4
3, 35, 4
3, 45, 5
3, 50, 6
```

how would I do the following please?

1. Access the value 50 in the first row (or any other single value in the table) on its own?
2. Access the values 50 and 55 (i.e. all values in column 2 given the first column (the key) = 1)? Could I get these as a list?
3. Delete the first row altogether?
4. Delete the first two rows (i.e delete all rows where the key = 1)
5. Add a row: 1, 25, 6

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what the name `table` implies, it is misleading to think about it in terms of rows and columns. The `table` extension gives you a data structure that is more commonly known as a "dictionary" or a "hash map": it associates keys with values.

In your example, the keys are numbers and the values are lists of lists of numbers. Thinking about it in any other way risks causing confusion.

That being said, here is how you would accomplish the operations you are asking about:

```
; Access the value 50 in the first row (or any other
; single value in the table) on its own?
print first first table:get t 1

; Access the values 50 and 55 (i.e. all values in column 2 given
; the first column (the key) = 1)? Could I get these as a list?
print map first table:get t 1

; Delete the first row altogether?
table:put t 1 but-first table:get t 1
print t  

; Delete the first two rows (i.e delete all rows where the key = 1)
table:remove t 1
print t

; Add a row: 1, 25, 6
let current-list ifelse-value ((table:has-key? t 1) and (is-list? table:get t 1)) [
  table:get t 1
] [
  (list) ; empty list
]
table:put t 1 lput [25 6] current-list 
print t
```

Result:

```
50
[50 55]
{{table: [[1 [[55 2]]] [2 [[20 3] [15 4]]] [3 [[35 4] [45 5] [50 6]]]]}}
{{table: [[2 [[20 3] [15 4]]] [3 [[35 4] [45 5] [50 6]]]]}}
{{table: [[2 [[20 3] [15 4]]] [3 [[35 4] [45 5] [50 6]]] [1 [[25 6]]]]}}
```

Notice how none of this looks like manipulating rows and columns.

Also notice that, for the last operation, I check whether or not there is already something associated with the key `1`. In this particular case, there would not be anything, since we just deleted it, but the code shows how to add to an existing list if need be.

Finally, notice that, after adding back our entry for key `1`, it appears at the end of the table. The `table` extension maintains its keys in their order of insertion, but you should probably not rely on that. It's best to think about the data structure as being unordered. Conceptually, it is a *set* of keys associated with values, and sets don't have a particular order.

#### Response to comments:

> What's the generic form of `print map first table:get t 1`, in order to get the values 1 and 2 (the 'column' 3 values when key=1)? `print map item 0 table:get t 1` won't work. `print map second table:get t 1` certainly won't work!

Using expressions like `map first some-list` becomes second nature after a while, but I tend to forget that they're not obvious to everyone. It is using 
the "concise syntax" for anonymous procedures (anonymous procedures used to be called "tasks" in NetLogo < 6.0).

Basically:

```
map first table:get t 1
```

is the equivalent of:

```
map [ my-sublist -> first my-sublist ] table:get t 1
```

(This is NetLogo 6.0.1 syntax.)

To be more explicit, `map` is a reporter primitive that takes two arguments: an anonymous reporter and a list. It passes each item of the list to the anonymous reporter and builds a new list out of the results. If the operation we want to apply to our list items happens to be a reporter taking the right number of arguments (in this case, one argument), we can pass the name of that reporter directly to `map` and it will automatically be turned into the appropriate anonymous reporter. To give a different example, `map sqrt [4 9 16]` is the same as `map [ n -> sqrt n ] [4 9 16]`.

Now you are right that `map item 1 table:get t 1` won't work. In such a case, we need to use the longhand syntax:

```
map [ my-sublist -> item 1 my-sublist ] table:get t 1
```

See the [anonymous procedures](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures) section of the programming guide for more details.

> Is there a generic form of `table:put t 1 but-first table:get t 1` that could delete the second or third 'row'?

```
let index 1 ; to remove the second item
table:put t 1 remove-item index table:get t 1
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas that's really helpful. Just in case others are searching for print second second table:get t 1, you can use print item 1 item 1 table:get t 1. The index starts at 0, so re-writing Nicholas' example would make it print item 0 item 0 table:get t 1

Comment: What's the generic form of print map first table:get t 1, in order to get the values 1 and 2 (the 'column' 3 values when key=1)? print map item 0 table:get t 1 won't work. print map second table:get t 1 certainly won't work!

Comment: Is there a generic form of table:put t 1 but-first table:get t 1 that could delete the second or third 'row'?